# MobX @observable decorator removes a field from a store

Tags: javascript, mobx

I am trying to understand MobX and create a simple store:

```
import { observable, autorun, computed } from "mobx";

class SomeStore {
  @observable someField = "";
}

const store = new SomeStore();
window.store = store;
export default store;
```

But `window.store` does not contain field `someField`. Without this decorator field is present in object.
Loaders in webpack.config:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015"],
                    plugins: ["react-html-attrs", "transform-class-properties", "transform-decorators-legacy"]
                },
                loader: "babel"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: How did you check if the object has `someField` or not? I think mobx makes a getter for the field so it may not appear as a normal field on the object. Try doing `window.store.someField` and see what you get.

Comment: `window.store.someField` returns undefined

Comment: That's definitely not the normal behavior. Could you check if any other module is overriding `window.store`? Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mdebbar/uyjoq1s0/4/ it works just fine.

Comment: I have checked, and any module does not override `window.store`. I have even tried `window.storeWithSuperUniqueName= store;` and the result was the same. Seems that is some unique problem. Thank you for try to help me! But I will try to do my task with redux because I have no more forces to trying to understand what is going wrong .

Answer (score 0):

The plugin `"transform-decorators-legacy"` should come *first* in your plugins list. The babel decorator rewrite needs to happen before the transform class properties.